# Mathematical induction (sum of the first few even numbers)

Tags: proof-writing, induction

So the question was basically "
*Suppose that there are n teams in a rugby league competition. Every team A
plays every other team B twice, once at the home ground for team A, and the other time
at the home ground for team B."*

***2(n  1) + 2(n  2) + 2(n  3) + : : : + 6 + 4 + 2  is given***

a) Write the expression in summation notation.
b) Use mathematical induction to prove it, n>=2

**So I got this expression for (a)**
n^Sigma(i=1) = (2(n-i))  where n is the number of teams

***Part B***

*Proof:*

Let P(n)  denote the sequence n^Sigma(i=1)=2(n-i)  and n≥2

Consider P (2)
n^Sigma(i=1)=2(n-i) =2(2-1)=2
∴it is true when n=2

**We will now assume it is true for P(k)**

k^Sigma(i=1)=2(k-i)  for some integer k ≥2

**Consider P(k+1)**

k+1^Sigma(i=1)=2(k+1-i)  for some integer k ≥2

P(k+1)=2(k-1)+2(k-2)+2(k-3)+⋯+2(k-i)+2(k+1-1)

*Since we have assumed that P(k) is true.*

*So we know*: P(k+1)=P(k)+(k+1)

**ANSWER** i cant answer my own question for 8hrs so here it is:

P(n)=n^2-n

P(K+1)=P(k)+2((k+1)-1)

P(K+1)=〖(k〗^2-k)+2(k+1)-2

P(K+1)=〖(k〗^2-k)+2(k+1)-2

P(K+1)=〖(k〗^2-k)+2k+2-2

P(K+1)=〖(k〗^2-k)+2k

P(K+1)=〖(k〗^2+k)

P(K+1)=(k+1)^2-(k+1)

Therefore under induction the sequence has been proven.

Thanks to @P..

Comment: The answer for part (a) is correct. But for part (b) what are you trying to prove? What do you think $P(k)$ equals to? Hint: [Arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

Comment: well P(k)=2(k-i)=2k-2i. Know P(K+1)=P(k)+k+1= 2(k-i)+(k+1) which brings me right back to where i am.

Comment: So can you tell me from your expression what $P(3)$, or $P(5)$ is? The answer should be a number.

Comment: @P.. So is P(k)=K^2-k?

Comment: Yes! Now try to prove it using induction. If you need any help let me know.

Comment: @P.. why does the i go to 1 and not to k? And thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The OP edited in an answer to his/her post; I'm copying it here so the question isn't "unanswered."

> $P(n)=n^2-n$
>
> $P(k+1)=P(k)+2((k+1)-1)$
>
> $P(k+1)= (k^2-k)+2(k+1)-2$
>
> $P(k+1)=(k^2-k)+2(k+1)-2$
>
> $P(k+1)=(k^2-k)+2k+2-2$
>
> $P(k+1)=(k^2-k)+2k$
>
> $P(k+1)=(k^2+k)$
>
> $P(k+1)=(k+1)^2-(k+1)$
>
> Therefore under induction the sequence has been proven.